# basketball shot chart css shape

Tags: html, css

Are these shapes possible in css? I have been trying a lot but nothing seems to work.

I finding it hard to get the right curvature.

My not working code:

```
 .col4 {
    width: 19%;
    height: 68%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 72px;
    border-left: 10px solid red;
    border-right: 10px solid blue;
    border-bottom: 10px solid green;
    border-top: 10px solid yellow;
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: border-radius ?

Comment: If you were tryin a lot, than put your code here, explain what you tried, how it looks and what the problem is: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Take a look at HTML5 SVG?

Comment: Thank you @Adriani6, svg is maybe what this needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Adriani6][1] said, using svg would work better for this.

I've added `:hover` state so you can see the zone boundaries:

```css
body {
  background: #2B2B2B;
}

.court {
  fill: #7A7A7A;
  stroke: #2B2B2B;
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.zone {
  fill: #7A7A7A;
  stroke: #2B2B2B;
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

.zone:hover {
  fill: #FEA400;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<svg id="basketball" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1280 1024">
  <rect x="25" y="31" class="court" width="1228" height="771"></rect>
  <rect x="25" y="31" class="zone" width="180" height="426"/>
  <rect x="1073" y="31" class="zone" width="180" height="426"/>
  <rect x="205" y="31" class="zone" width="234" height="250"/>
  <rect x="839" y="31" class="zone" width="234" height="250"/>
  <rect x="439" y="31" class="zone" width="200" height="250"/>
  <rect x="439" y="281" class="zone" width="200" height="250"/>
  <path class="zone" d="M439,687.6v114.5h400v-115c-61,28.4-128.9,44.3-200.5,44.3C567.3,731.5,499.7,715.8,439,687.6z"/>
  <path class="zone" d="M439,531v156.6c60.7,27.8,128.3,43.4,199.5,43.4c71.6,0,139.5-15.7,200.5-43.8V531H439z"/>
  <path class="zone" d="M205,457h0.1c0-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.3V457z"/>
  <path class="zone" d="M205,281v175.7c0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3C253.5,558.7,336.5,640.7,439,687.6V531v-74V281H205z"/>
  <path class="zone" d="M1073,457v-2.4c-0.4,0.8-0.8,1.6-1.2,2.4H1073z"/>
  <path class="zone" d="M839,281v176v74v156.2c102-47,184.7-128.8,232.8-230.2c0.4-0.8,0.8-1.6,1.2-2.4V281H839z"/>
  <rect x="639" y="281" class="zone" width="200" height="250"/>
  <rect x="639" y="31" class="zone" width="200" height="250"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: You're awesome, @joshmoto .. and it's responsive too .. svg is the way to go

Comment: @joshmoto - awesome solution!